# How to fix this Android Firebase "client offline" error

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to connect my android application to Firebase. But it shows "**Failed to get document because the client is offline**" toast when the app run. I see the splash screen but I get the toast and does not navigate to the first activity.

```
  private void loadData() {
   catList.clear();
    firestore.collection("QuizApp").document("Categories").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            if(documentSnapshot.exists()){
                long count = (long)documentSnapshot.get("COUNT");

                for(int i=1; i<=count; i++){
                    String catName = documentSnapshot.getString("CAT"+ String.valueOf(i));
                    catList.add(catName);
                }
                final Intent anim_int = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(anim_int);
                SplashScreen.this.finish();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this,"No any categories",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: check internet connection , also check if you added internet permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: @ManoharReddy Hi Manohar, thank you for replying. There is no problem with internet connection. I added internet permission too.

Comment: update the firebase libraries and check

Comment: Can you add a dummy document to  QuizApp collection in Firestore

Comment: @sjmach It already have documents. I want to retrieve data. Can you check the image please?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x9sE5hHifsaNs1Eu-jCnJVhckYcN3-DT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello MrKaV, can you add the complete code. I am interested if the init() function works.   db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
                .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
                .build();
        db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);